# Exchange of coordinates in GeoPandas

Tags: python, coordinates, geopandas, latitude-longitude, plot

I was plotting some points with the plot function in GeoPandas. I realized that when I plotted using `Point.lat`, `Point.long`, the points didn't fall at the right place but when I exchanged the coordinates to the format `Point.long`, `Point.lat`, the points fell at the right places. Can anyone explain this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the [GeoPandas](https://geopandas.org/) documentation:

[image: doc]

Source: https://geopandas.readthedocs.io/en/latest/gallery/create_geopandas_from_pandas.html

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49635530/6630397

Answer (score 1):

Longitude is typically the "X" value and Latitude is the "Y" value.  Point pairs are usually in [x,y] format.  [x,y,z] in 3D